# Java Eclipse PhoneGap. Can't Setup a Plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, cordova, android-softkeyboard

I'm obviously very new to Java and I'm having a hard time getting a PhoneGap plugin to work. I don't know where to put my java file

(*Using Cordova 2.9.0)

**The instructions say to:**

*create /src/com/phonegap/plugins/SoftKeyboard with provided file SoftKeyBoard.java inside*

The .java file can be found here: ---> [java file](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SoftKeyboard)

I don't know what to create when I right-click on the 'com' package in the src folder. Do I create a class?

[image]

Comment: Please let me know why you down-vote.

Comment: Right click on src and add new package name: com.phonegap.plugins, you can then add your SoftKeyboard.java file there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneGap provides a template builder command line already assembles your project, and add a test page, from a look at this link that explains how to do: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/guide_command-line_index.md.html